# How to create login (MySQL) with multiple types of user in Android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I want to create login activity with multiple types of user. This login is connected with MySQL. The multiple choice is "Reviewer" and "Non-Reviewer". Now I use Spinner and the values I call from string.xml. At the table 'user', there are some column such as 'username', 'password', and 'usertype'. Example, user 'peter' is a "Reviewer", he will able to login if user name, password and user type that he uses is correct. How can i solve this problem? Below is my code.

//login activity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

```
private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://lienawan.xyz/login.php";

private SharedPreferences.Editor loginPrefsEditor;

private EditText etEmail;
private EditText etPassword;
private CheckBox chkMe;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //will hide the title
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide(); // hide the title ba
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    chkMe = findViewById(R.id.chkMe);
    SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    loginPrefsEditor = loginPreferences.edit();
    boolean saveLogin = loginPreferences.getBoolean("saveLogin", false);
    if (saveLogin) {
        etEmail.setText(loginPreferences.getString("username", ""));
        etPassword.setText(loginPreferences.getString("password", ""));
        chkMe.setChecked(true);
    }
    Spinner spCategory = findViewById(R.id.spCategory);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.usertype,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
    spCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    Button btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            login();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(etEmail.getWindowToken(), 0);

            String username = etEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            if (chkMe.isChecked()) {
                loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean("saveLogin", true);
                loginPrefsEditor.putString("username", username);
                loginPrefsEditor.putString("password", password);
                loginPrefsEditor.apply();
            } else {
                loginPrefsEditor.clear();
                loginPrefsEditor.commit();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Exit");
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            finish();

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

private void login() {

    String username = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    userLogin(username, password);
}

private void userLogin(final String username, final String password){
    class UserLoginClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
        private ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Login... Please Wait",null,true,true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DashboardApp.class);
                intent.putExtra(KEY_USERNAME,username);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("username",params[0]);
            data.put("password",params[1]);

            Connection ruc = new Connection();
            String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(LOGIN_URL,data);
            return result;
        }
    }
    UserLoginClass ulc = new UserLoginClass();
    ulc.execute(username, password);
}
```

}

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $approver = $_POST['approver'];

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $sql = "select * from user where username='$username' and password='$password'";

    $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

    if(isset($check)){
        echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "Invalid Username or Password";
    }

}else{
    echo "error try again";
```

Comment: "How can i solve this problem?"—what problem? You've got a bunch of code, how is it failing to do what you want? Please read [ask].

Comment: Now login is successful(without multiple user). But I want to know how to do login with multiple types of user.

Comment: Your code is _**wide open** to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)_. Don't build queries by sticking strings together. Instead, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: Also, it is _**never**_ store passwords in plain text. Use
[`password_hash()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to store and check hashed passwords instead.

Comment: What change do the multiple user types make to your authentication code? It should still work, right?

Comment: can teach me? authentication when choosing user type, spinner

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get selected value from spinner you write below code in `onItemSelected` :

```
 String item;//declare globally out of your all method
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Now,check if `item` and other value are `not null` , like below  :

```
    private void login() {

        String username = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        //checking if fields are not null 
       if (username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || item.isEmpty()) {
       Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Please enter name or pass or select one type!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
        }else{
          userLogin(username, password,item);//passing value to volley
     }
   }
```

And in your volley request change like below :

```
    private void userLogin(final String username, final String password,final String item){
...
 @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("username",params[0]);
            data.put("password",params[1]);
            data.put("approver",params[2]);//adding item value
            ..
        }
    }
}
```

At your php side just change your `query` to :

```
 $sql = "select * from user where username='$username' and password='$password' and usertype='$approver'";
```

Hope this helps you !

***Note*** : Also never used [**plain-text password**](https://dev.to/restoreddev/security-tips-for-a-php-application-4e9a) and try using [**prepared statement**](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) it is safe an secure.

Comment: That query is still extremely dangerous since it has unescaped data(!) and plain-text passwords(!!) in it.

Comment: True, but it's still hazardous. To promote good practices we should at least express it with placeholder values and leave filling those in as an exercise for anyone looking to use the code.